# Prolog - Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated. lists/recursion

Tags: list, prolog, instantiation-error

I am trying to get the maximum number from a given list 'L' and assign it to a variable, so I used to write the following function:

```
max(L,X):-
    [H|Q]=L,
    (X<H -> X=H),
    length(Q,QLEN),
    (QLEN>0 -> max(Q,X)),
    true.
```

However after compiling the code and prompting `max([1,2,3],X)` within [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/), I get the following error:

> ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated ERROR: In: ERROR:
> [9] _1064<1 ERROR:    [8] max([1,2|...],_1092) at c:/users/kais/desktop/tp3.pl:24 ERROR:    [7]

Why I'm getting such error?

Comment: Because `X` does not have a value when you try to compare it with `H`. That whole line makes no sense in Prolog. You need some other parameter for the max value so far.

Comment: Don't try to compute the length at each step. The search ends when the list is empty.

Comment: @TomasBy If I initialize X within the function, I lose its value for the next recursion.

Comment: @coredump okay.

Comment: How can I initialize X?

Comment: @Kais: in the answer below, the base case of `maxList/3` is where your `X` gets instantiated, ie at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comment you try to compare `H` with `X` which is not instantiated. A solution to this problem is to create a predicate `maxList/3` and call it inside `maxList/2` as follows:

```
maxList([H|T], Max) :-
    maxList(T, H, Max).

maxList([], Max, Max).
maxList([H|T], Max0, Max) :-
    Max1 is max(H, Max0),
    maxList(T, Max1, Max).

?- maxList([1,2,3],X).
X = 3.
```

`max/2` simply returns the max between two arguments. A possible implementation for `max/2` could be:

```
myMax(M,A,B):-
    A > B ->  M = A;
    M = B.

?- myMax(A,1,2).
A = 2.
```

BTW, there is already a built in predicate in SWI to do this, which is called `max_list/2` (the code I posted before actually comes from this implementation):

```
?- max_list([1,2,3],X).
X = 3.
```

Comment: After trying the method, I get an error https://gist.github.com/kaisbe/29e55f380838c64d48fd500e964429a2

Comment: To help OP' learning process, would be nice to show the proper way to perform the computation *without* an accumulator. And, maybe, also the alternative using negation and member/2 instead of recursion...

Comment: @Kais you cannot call one of your predicates as an arithmetic function in Prolog. So the code you linked to isn't valid on this line: `Max1 is maxP(H, Max0)`. `is/2` expects known Prolog arithmetic functions in the expression. Why don't you use the existing Prolog `max/2` arithmetic function as this answer shows? Alternatively, you could make your version of `maxP` have 3 arguments as this answer shows with `myMax`.

Comment: @lurker I'm used to do a HW requiring me to implement `max(L,X)`.

Comment: @Kais if you have to implement your own `max` then you will need to use the 3-argument approach that this answer shows. You simply cannot redefine your own arithmetic function in SWI Prolog.

Comment: @lurker ok, understood.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible implementation, not relying on an auxiliary predicate, can be done according to the following logic:

1. If the list contains exactly one element, then it is the maximum.
2. If the list `L` contains more than one element, i.e. it is of the form `[H|T]`, and the greatest element of `T` is `M`, then the greatest element of `L` will be `H` if `H>=M`, otherwise it will be `M`.

A rough encoding could be:

```
maxList([X],X).
maxList([H|T],H) :-
  maxList(T,M),
  H >= M.
maxList([H|T],M) :-
  maxList(T,M),
  H < M.
```

This leaves room for improvement, but respects the logic above stated and returns the greatest element for each non-empty integer list.